# Defining quantum memory mathematically

Tags: quantum-state, information-theory, quantum-memory

Is it possible that we may define the notion of quantum memory in abstract manner, that is, mathematically? A definition which is hardware independent that may be treated as a mathematical object. We define quantum channel as CPTP map that serve as a medium through which information transfers from one point to another. I would like to know whether we could define memory in quantum system in a similar fashion.

Like bits in classical systems, we have qubits in quantum systems. We have mathematical description of a *state* of qubit in terms of linear combination of pure states. I suppose that a state of qubit cannot be taken as a representation of quantum memory. For it does not sound plausible as this would imply a qubit has infinite memory capacity (as it has infinite states) in comparison with classical system (such as deterministic finite automata).

Naively speaking, qubit has two memory aspects: Carrying the information, and retrieving the information from what it is carrying along with it. A qubit can carry huge amount of information in comparison with classical bits but the information that we may want to access anytime is just up to two classical bits. This information carrying capacity is certainly not the information storage capacity but in some naive sense it is still memory like.

An information storage should contain the information that can be retrieved at any moment but this is not happening with qubit. To me then, qubit has two kind of memory: *inaccessible memory* and *accessible memory*. This inaccessible memory may go through number of quantum processes applied on the qubit. As we perform the measurement, the qubit loses all the information except what remain in the accessible memory.

So qubit is also serving as an information storage which is available for manipulation by means of transformations allowed yet remain inaccessible. Consequently, the notion of quantum memory should be more general than the notion of memory storage in the classical sense.

To sum up, a qubit can "store" arbitrary large amount information in its inaccessible memory however from this "stored" information only two bits can be "retrieved" which become accessible memory of qubit.

Please bear with the repetitions which are results of my confusion to make sense of quantum memory in comparison with classical memory.